# Why is set() constructor slower than list()

Tags: python, list, performance, set

I timed `set()` and `list()` constructors. `set()` was significantly slower than `list()`. I benchmarked them using values where no duplicates exist. I know set use hashtables is it reason it's slower?

I'm using Python **3.7.5** [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], **Windows 10**, as of this writing( 8<sup>th</sup> March).

```
#No significant changed observed.
timeit set(range(10))
517 ns ± 4.91 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
timeit list(range(10))
404 ns ± 4.71 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

When the size increases `set()` became very slower than `list()`

```
# When size is 100
timeit set(range(100))
2.13 µs ± 12.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
timeit list(range(100))
934 ns ± 10.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

# when size is ten thousand.
timeit set(range(10000))
325 µs ± 2.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
timeit list(range(10000))
240 µs ± 2.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# When size is one million.
timeit set(range(1000000))
86.9 ms ± 1.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
timeit list(range(1000000))
37.7 ms ± 396 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Both of them take **`O(n)`** asymptotically. When there are no duplicates shouldn't `set(...)` approximately equal be to `list(...)`.

To my surprise *set comprehension* and *list comprehension* didn't show those huge deviations like `set()` and `list()` showed.

```
# When size is 100. 
timeit {i for i in range(100)}
3.96 µs ± 858 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
timeit [i for i in range(100)]
3.01 µs ± 265 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# When size is ten thousand.
timeit {i for i in range(10000)}
434 µs ± 5.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
timeit [i for i in range(10000)]
395 µs ± 13.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# When size is one million.
timeit {i for i in range(1000000)}
95.1 ms ± 2.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
timeit [i for i in range(1000000)]
87.3 ms ± 760 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why should they be the same? Yes, they are both O(n) but `set()` needs to *hash each element* and needs to account for elements not being unique. This translates to a higher *fixed cost per element*.

Big O says nothing about absolute times, only how the time taken will grow as the size of the input grows. Two O(n) algorithms, given the same inputs, can take vastly different amounts of time to complete. All you can say is that when the size of the input doubles, the amount of time taken will (roughly) double, for both functions.

If you want to understand Big O better, I highly recommend [Ned Batchelder’s introduction to the subject](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/bigo.html).

> When there are no duplicates shouldn't set(...) approximately equal be to list(...).

No, they are not equal, because `list()` doesn't hash. That there are no duplicates doesn't figure.

> To my suprise set comprehension and list comprehension didn't show those huge deviations like `set()` and `list()` showed.

The additional loop executed by the Python interpreter loop adds overhead that dominates the time taken. The higher fixed cost of `set()` is then less prominent.

There are other differences that may make a difference:

- Given a *sequence* with a known length, `list()` can pre-allocate enough memory to fit those elements. Sets can't pre-allocate as they can't know how many duplicates there will be. Pre-allocating avoids the (amortised) cost of having to grow the list dynamically.
- List and set comprehensions add one element at a time, so list objects can't preallocate, increasing the fixed per-item cost slightly.

Comment: @Ch3steR Can’t go wrong with *Fluent Python* by Luciano Ramalho, published by O’Reilly. (disclaimer: I am not connected with the publisher in any way, but know Luciano well and he thanks me in the acknowledgments).

Comment: @Ch3steR And my former colleague and friend Matt Wilkes has a brand new book *Advanced Python Development* (published by Apress) that may be worth your time as well, but I haven’t read it yet. It is due out September this year.

Comment: @Ch3steR: https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484257920. Also listed on Amazon for pre-order.